# Can a Slowed Character Escape a Maze spell?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

According to [this](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/slow.htm), "A slowed creature can take only a single move action or standard action each turn". However, escaping a [Maze](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Maze) is a full round action. Barring the use of plane shift, does this mean that a slowed creature has no possible way of escaping the Maze spell and must remain there for the full 10 minutes? Or does time in the Maze flow like time in the normal plane and the victim needs to wait for X rounds for Slow to wear off before attempting an escape?

Really I guess this is a question about the flow of time in the Maze extradimensional space.

Comment: Can I just say that Maze is one of my favorite spells specifically because it doesn't work on Minotaurs? That's some tasty flavor right there.

Comment: @GreedyRadish Not just Maze, they just plain can't get lost or be flat-footed due to inherent memory and logical skills. I'm amazed that not only did they work the flavour in, but that they managed to turn a piece of mythological fluff into a plausible racial quirk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes, a *slow*ed creature can still escape

There is a relatively obscure rule hiding in the Player's Handbook - [Start/Complete Full-round Action](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#startCompleteFullRoundAction)

> The "start full-round action" standard action lets you start undertaking a full-round action, which you can complete in the following round by using another standard action. You can’t use this action to start or complete a full attack, charge, run, or withdraw.

So a *slow*ed creature can use a standard action this round, and a standard action next round, instead of the full-round action necessary to escape the *maze*.

## Yes, a *slow*ed creature can wait out *slow* inside the *maze*

Creatures explicitly get their turns inside the *maze*:

> Each round on its turn, it may attempt a DC 20 Intelligence check to escape the labyrinth as a full-round action...a plane shift spell allows it to exit to whatever plane is designated in that spell

This text would make no sense if time was not passing for these creatures (because then they could not take actions). No mention is made of the *maze* plane being timeless, either. So the victim's spell effects are ticking down, whether the *slow* debuff, or any buffs (such as the *fox's cunning* the creature might cast upon itself to give it better odds of succeeding on the INT check to escape).